# presentModalViewController - UIToolbar below something invisible

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, uitoolbar, presentmodalviewcontroller

I'm calling a `UIViewController` and presenting it like this in a navigation-based project:

```
[self presentModalViewController:self.controller animated:YES];
```

On the top of the controller I have a `UIToolBar` with 2 buttons which I created in the IB. Everything appears, but there is something invisible on the top of my `UIToolBar`. I concluded that because if I click on one of the buttons, nothing happens. If I click on the very top (the bar where the time is), then the button is activated. The area where I click and nothing happens is the same as the navigation bar. If that's the case, how can I put my view over the navigation bar, so that the buttons on my toolbar are accessible?

Comment: Post the code so we can have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I have it working properly! I have to call `presentModalViewController` with a `UINavigationController` and not my own controller, which is a subclass of `UIViewController`. Here it is some code, in case it helps someone:

```
UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.contr];
[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
[navController release];
```

And in the viewDidLoad, inside the controller:

```
UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemCancel target:self action:@selector(goBack:)];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = cancelButton;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
yourView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
```

Comment: I don't understand how can that make my buttons accessible or make the view over the navigation bar.

Comment: @Adriana, Perhaps I misunderstood you, but it sounded like you had a view on top of your tool bar that was receiving the touches instead of the buttons. Disabling the user interaction of that view will send the touches to the buttons instead.